# Phonegap and Facebook plugin returning status unknown

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We need to share some information on user's profile page in Facebook using Phonegap.

To do that, we are trying with the [Phonegap facebook plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin). As the phonegap app is still in development, we have created an app in Facebook as we understand that an app id is needed. We created the app and tested, but we are getting this status:

{"status":"unknown"}

with this error message:

No active session

Of course I have added the Android configuration to test in Facebook, with the Google Play Package Name and class, the hash, and tested enabling and disabling the sso. Nothing worked so far.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this, I have the same issue.

Comment: No, I didn't. Finally the requirements changed and we did not continue on this.

Comment: I was getting status unknown when I used the share method of 'feed' as this required an active session (which I believe means the user is logged into your app using FB login).  Changing the share method to 'share' resolved this as you do no need any permissions form the user.

Comment: Great! Could you share your solution, detailed, as answer to this question instead of a comment, please? It surely will help other people with the same issue. Thanks!